# Setup Multisite WordPress on WampDeveloper Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

Hi After install success network multisite On Server I want Install it on local host with WampDeveloper Pro and after finish basic setting and reach to logout and login to WordPress after enter my username and pass nothing happen and cant login to site and i change my user and pass many time from database to md5 and nothing happing

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'wordpress');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Comment: i install on cpanel multi-site fine with subdomain and many themes and plugins but in local fresh install not work